# Change image on refresh

Tags: javascript, image

How can i change image on refresh, but to that image have a link still? Here is what i've tried:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
var theImages = new Array()

//Random-loading images
theImages[0] = 'image' // replace with names of images
theImages[1] = 'image' // replace with names of images

var j = 0
var p = theImages.length;
var preBuffer = new Array()

for (i = 0; i < p; i++){
preBuffer[i] = new Image()
preBuffer[i].src = theImages[i]
}
var whichImage = Math.round(Math.random()*(p-1));

function showImage(){
    if(whichImage==0){
    document.write('<a href ="link"><img src="'+theImages[0]+'" border=1 width=728 height=90></a>');
    }
    else if(whichImage==1){
    document.write('<a href ="link"><img src="'+theImages[whichImage]+'" border=0 width=728 height=90></a>');
    }
}

</script>
<script>showImage();</script>
```

I found that on net and few more codes, but everything doesn't work for me :( Can someone fix this code or help me other way? :)

Comment: What do you mean on refresh? You mean when the page reloads? If so you will need to use something like `localstorage` or a `cookie` to know what the last image was on display.

Comment: Yep, i mean on reload. I know more than basic in coding, but...i don't know that much :/

Comment: When the page reloads javascript is will start over again with no record of previous executions. You will need to use some sort of storage to know what the last image url was displayed to know it needs changing. I recommend you research cookies or localstorage. Personally I would go for localstorage.

Comment: I understood, but...ahhh nevermind :$

Comment: But what? You want to know if it's possible and i'm pointing you towards two methods of doing this, I'm not sure if you expected source code but to answer this question it doesn't need source code, just a point in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

This will select an image at random on each run and set the html img's src attribute accordingly.

```js
var images = [
  'image_1.jpg',
  'image_2.jpg',
  'image_3.jpg',
  'image_4.jpg',
  'image_5.jpg'
]

var which = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
var img = document.getElementById('theimage');
img.src = images[which];
img.title = images[which];
```

```html
<img id="theimage" />
```

Comment: This will select a random image but doesn't guarantee a new image upon refresh so I don't think this answers the question.