# Replace random image on website

Tags: javascript, image, random

my goal is to replace one random image from open website with some random image from my list of images. I have this code, but It changes all the images on the website, I need just one random not all of them. Can you help me please with it?

```
//Handles all images on page with an interval of time
        handleImages: function (lstImgs, time) {
            $.each($('img'), function (i, item) {
                //Skip if image is already replaced
                if ($.inArray($(item).attr('src'), lstImgs) == -1) {
                    var h = $(item).height();
                    var w = $(item).width();

                    //If image loaded
                    if (h > 0 && w > 0) {

                        self.handleImg(item, lstImgs);
                    }
                    else {
                        //Replace when loaded
                        $(item).load(function () {
                            //Prevent 'infinite' loop
                            if ($.inArray($(item).attr('src'), lstImgs) == -1) {
                                self.handleImg(item, lstImgs);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });

            //Keep replacing
            if (time > 0) {
                setTimeout(function () { self.handleImages(lstImgs, time); }, time);
            }
        },
        //Replace one image
        handleImg: function (item, lstImgs) {
            $(item).error(function () {
                //Handle broken imgs
                self.handleBrokenImg(item, lstImgs);
            });

            self.setRandomImg(item, lstImgs);
        },
        //Set a random image from lstImgs to item 
        setRandomImg: function (item, lstImgs) {
            var h = $(item).height();
            var w = $(item).width();
            $(item).css('width', w + 'px').css('height', h + 'px');
            $(item).attr('src', lstImgs[Math.floor(Math.random() * lstImgs.length)]);
        },
        //Removed broken image from lstImgs, run handleImg on item
        handleBrokenImg: function (item, lstImgs) {

            var brokenImg = $(item).attr('src');
            var index = lstImgs.indexOf(brokenImg);
            if (index > -1) {
                lstImgs.splice(index, 1);
            }
            self.setRandomImg(item, lstImgs);
        },
    };

    //Run on jQuery ready
    $(function () {

        self.handleImages(self.gitmbImgs, 3000);

    });

    //Set global variable
    $.gitmb = self;
```

Comment: Check this answer out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419024/change-image-on-refresh/#answer-30419621

Answer (score 0):

`$.each($('img')` selects all images, all you need is one.

Update

```
<img src="https://thereisnocavalry.files.wordpress.com/2012/08/fractals-erucolindo3.jpg" alt="some image">

<img src="http://ionamiller.weebly.com/uploads/4/7/9/5/4795680/5133447.jpg?617" alt="some image">

<img src="http://wallpoper.com/images/00/17/31/50/abstract-fractal_00173150.jpg" alt="some image">

<img src="http://www.wussu.com/fractals/images/wd950112.gif" alt="some image">

<img src="http://naperdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/fractals_generative.jpg" alt="some image">


$().ready(function() {
    var imagesToReplace = $("img");
    var imagesReplaced  = [];
    var imagesAvailable = [
        "http://www.hdwallpapersn.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Fractal-Pictures-3.jpg",
        "http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs27/f/2008/073/c/e/Fractals_of_the_Ball_by_Hosse7.jpg",
        "https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTQKqS8FDvMUcbsUTQj8TIbHg7JSIpvcQqWax9Pq5gZX2BcoVIm",
        "http://www.sgeier.net/fractals/fractals/01/Fire%20and%20Water.jpg",
        "http://www.fractalsciencekit.com/fractals/large/Fractal-Mobius-Dragon-IFS-10.jpg",
        "https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQV44vnqHs24LfEEmMPKXojB4whOyBMnQbXghk2kJnkeP90bSR8" 
    ];

    var replaceImage = function() {
         var repl_ind, with_ind, img;
        if ( !imagesAvailable.length ) {
            //loop once all images have been replaced
            imagesAvailable = imagesReplaced.slice();
            imagesReplaced = [];          
         }

         repl_ind = Math.floor( Math.random() * imagesToReplace.length );
         with_ind = Math.floor( Math.random() * imagesAvailable.length );

         img = $(imagesToReplace.get(repl_ind));
         console.log("replacing",img.attr("src"),"with",imagesAvailable[with_ind]);

         imagesReplaced.push( img.attr("src") );
         img.attr("src", imagesAvailable[with_ind] );
         imagesAvailable.splice(with_ind, 1);
         //start timer once image is ready, either instantly or after load
        if ( img.get(0).complete ) { 
            setTimeout(replaceImage, 2000 );
            console.log("complete");
            img.get(0).onload=false;
        } else {
            console.log("onload");
            img.get(0).onload = function() {setTimeout(replaceImage, 1000 );};
        }
    }

    setTimeout(replaceImage, 4000 );
});


img {
    width: 6em;
    padding: 0.4em;
    height: 5em;
}
```

This is [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/aza2u1sf/7/).

Comment: Thank You for reply, but could you please edit my code with Your suggestion? It would helped me a lot, I am a bit lost. Dont know what I am doing anymoar...

Comment: i created a simpler sample, which you can use. /* updated the post */